# scrapy image pipeline filename unsing other crawled info

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Is there any way to name a crawled image with other info(text) that we get with the spider?
for example in this case I want images with the article title and article published date that I got in spider:

**spider file**

```
# lines of code 

def parse(self, response):

    # lines of code 

    yield {
            'date':date,
            'title': article_title,
            'image_urls': clean_urls
    }
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class customImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        return f"images/{request.url.split('/')[-1]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about this is to overwrite the `get_media_requests` method and set the image name there on the image requests `meta` attribute, so you can access it in the `file_path` method.

The following example will work if you pass one image url as string to `image_urls`:

```py
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline


class customImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return Request(
            item["image_urls"],
            meta = {
                "image_name": f"{item['title']}_{item['date']}",
            }
        )

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None) -> str:
        return f"images/{request.meta['image_name']}.jpg"
```